# htaccess question mark redirect multiple different static URLs

Tags: .htaccess

I wan't to redirect the following URLs:

1.
FROM: http://www.example.com/tr/component/content/article?id=11
TO: http://www.example.com/services/terms/

2.
FROM: http://www.example.com/tr/component/content/article?id=45
TO: http://www.example.com/services/cars/

I have the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=11
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/services/terms/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=45
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/services/cars/? [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But with the above code I can write the following - and end up at the "terms" page:

http://example.com?id=11

Which is wrong. What should I change?

Comment: In the first place controlling routing via htaccess is bad idea for future maintaining. What would if you add more pages? Should you list every page there? What if you change id of article? What if you change host and it does not support htaccess? Routing should be handled by your application.

Comment: Its just does two URLs I need to redirect, so thats not a problem. But I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is no other source of redirection.

I just pasted your `.htaccess` into my Apache and everything works like you wanted it to.

Edit: according to your comment, you can just replace `(.*)` rule with the base of URL you want your redirect to work on:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=11
RewriteRule /?tr/component/content/article(.*) http://www.example.com/services/terms/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=45
RewriteRule /?tr/component/content/article(.*) http://www.example.com/services/cars/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But it works "to much". You can write http://example.com/what-ever-you-want-here?id=11 and end up at the "terms" page. I don't wont this to happen. That you can write whatever you want before the id -tag

Comment: Oh, I get it. Edited the answer.

Comment: @JohnSmith In that case stop just checking query string and check requested url. ;)